# Getting 401 error code in Angularjs and .Net Web API

Tags: c#, angularjs, angular, angular2-forms, http2

I am hosting my .Net API (client is in Angularjs) app on windows server 2016. Currently, HTTP/2 is by default enabled on windows server 2016 due to which I am getting Authorization error with error code 401 on Login.

This application is working fine on Windows server 2012 R2

In Logs:

> 2019-05-22
>
> 05:04:45.5726|ERROR|ParseHeaderHandler|ATI.Oasis.Web.API.Core.Utilities.Message
>
> Handlers.ParseHeaderHandler.HandleError | RequestID b646b6a8-c20c-4dc7-b360-
>
> 0e5664478935| Authorization token is not present or is invalid.|

The current webAPI is supporting 4.7.2 .net framework and client side is in Angularjs.
I am using the following code to Login:

```js
function getUnauthenticated(url, hideLoading, hideError) {
            if (!hideLoading) {
                LoadingService.show();
            }
            console.log('HOSTNAME:' + getHost());
            console.log('URL:' + url);
            var request = $http.get(getHost() + url, { headers: { 'Key': getAccessKey() }, withCredentials: true });
            console.log('GET:' + getHost() + url);
            console.log('withcredential - true');
            console.log(request);
            if (hideError) {
                return (request.then(handleSuccess, handleErrorWithoutPopup));
            } else {
                return (request.then(handleSuccess, handleError));
            }
        }

function getAccessKey() {
            return sessionStorage.AccessKey;
        }
```

[Request and Response headers of GET call (Image link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byaxW.png)

Question is: Unauthorized error (401) when accessing webapi from angularjs

Comment: can anyone help on this issue, its very urgent for me.

Comment: It rather sounds like a misconfiguration, not related to HTTP/2.

Comment: aps.net core application is using HTTP/1.1 by default. are you sure that the error is related to HTTP configuration? you want to force your app to use HTTP/2?

Comment: currently i am using 4.7.2 framework. Reason due to which i am sure this issue is related to HTTP/2 protocol because this app works fine on WS 2012 R2 but same app doesn't work on WS 2016. I have no option to move my current app on .net core.